# Catch up with someone: Aufholen or Einholen?

Tags: word-choice

How do I say ''catch up with the class/peers'' or '' catch up with someone" regarding gaining the missed knowlegde to be on the same level as someone else? Könnt ihr mir auch einige Beispielsätze geben?

Comment: Hast Du gar keine Vorstellung, wie mit den Worten ein Satz zu bilden wäre?

Answer (score 2):

You "einholen" somebody who's in front of you, and you "aufholen" the distance between the two of you.

> Mein Freund ist schon früher losgegangen, aber ich kann ihn noch einholen.
> My friend left earlier, but I can still catch up with him.

> Das gegnerische Team liegt drei Tore vorne, aber das können wir noch aufholen.
> The opposing team is three goals in front, but we can still make up for that.

So, "to catch up the class" could be expressed as

> Sie musste viel lernen, aber sie hat es geschafft, die restliche Klasse einzuholen.
> She had to learn a lot, but she managed to catch up to the rest of the class.

or

> Sie musste viel lernen, aber sie hat es geschafft, ihren Rückstand aufzuholen.
> She had to learn a lot, but she managed to make up for her backlog.

By the way, if you do something later than you were supposed to do it originally, another similar verb comes into play, being "nachholen" (to make good for something, to rectify an omission):

> Er konnte die Prüfung nicht zum vorgesehen Termin ablegen, aber er kann sie noch nachholen.
> He couldn't take the exam at the scheduled date, but he still can make good for it (by taking the exam at a later date).